# SQL UNION ALL execution speed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to transfer a SSIS package into Python. There is a UNION ALL Editor in the package and, since I have no experience of using SSIS and very limited experience of using SQL, I suppose it equals to the `UNION ALL` command in SQL. The DBMS is MS SQL Server 2008.

So I am testing following code in Python:

```
SELECT *
INTO union_tabl
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 10 
           col1
    ,      col2
    ,      col3
    ,      ......
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP 10
           col1
    ,      col2
    ,      col3
    ,      ......
    FROM table2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP 10
           col1
    ,      col2
    ,      col3
    ,      ......
    FROM table3
)
```

There are 63 columns and about 78 millions rows in the tables, and in order to test the speed, I only select the top 10 rows from each of the tables. However, the above code takes way `much more time than I expected`.

Also, during the execution that select `all the rows` from the tables, the program crashed few times because SQL could not allocate new page for the database. (I have checked the file size, and it tooks about 500 GB.)

So I am wondering: (1) Is this the normal execution speed and consumption of disk space? Did I make any mistake to make it so slow and took so much disk space? (2) how I can optimize the code to make it faster?

Many thanks.

Comment: Instead of combining all tables into one large with unions, maybe you could insert the data from each table separately with `insert into union_tabl (col1, col2 ...) select (col1, col2 ...) from tableN` ? That way you wouldn't have to handle all data in one step.

Comment: How much time is "way much more time than I expected"?  How does the time change if you change `10` to `100` (I'm guessing it will barely budge)?  Is there any `order by` in your query?